# Jquery autofill select options

Tags: jquery, html, select

1. I have three select options with the same class = 'film'
2. I have a list that stores all select options.
3. When click on any list item, the first select option will be changed and I want to autofill the others select options with option = '---'

   ```
   <select id="pa_sc30-glossy-colors" name="attribute_pa_sc30-glossy-colors" class="film">
       <option value="">Choose color…</option>
       <option class="active" id="440" value="440" hidden="hidden">---</option>
       <option class="active" id="30-23-stone-yellow" value="30-23-stone-yellow">30-23 Stone Yellow</option>
       <!-- other options... -->
   </select>

   <select id="pa_sc30-glossy-colors" name="attribute_pa_sc30-glossy-colors" class="film">
       <option value="">Choose color…</option>
       <option value="">---</option>
   </select>

   <select id="pa_sc30-glossy-colors" name="attribute_pa_sc30-glossy-colors" class="film">
       <option value="">Choose color…</option>
       <option value="">---</option>
   </select>
   ```

jQuery:

```
// All options are stored in array 'var arr []'
// Each value of the array is stored in the tag '<li>'
// tag '<li>' is added to the list <ul class = "choose_variations">

 var list = $('.choose_variations');

  // Append list items to ul.choose_variations
   $('.film option').each(function(i) {
        $('<li>').text($(this).text()).data('val',$(this).val()).appendTo(list);
   });

   // Remove '---' and 'Choose color' list items    
   $('.choose_variations li').filter(function() {
        if( $(this).text() == '---' || $(this).text() == 'Choose color…') {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });


   // change select option if is clicked on list item
   $('.choose_variations li').click(function() {
        $('.film').val($(this).data('val'));
   });
```

Here is [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/jbjaksq8/9/)

Comment: Your question is incomplete. What should the other dropdowns be filled with once any color is selected from dropdown 1?

Comment: When click on any list item, the first dropdown will be changed, but the others should be filled with first option automatically.

Comment: So you mean to say, if you select "30-23 Stone Yellow", dropdown 2 and 3 will have "30-23 Stone Yellow" populated only?

Comment: No, If you select "30-23 Stone Yellow" from list, first dropdown will be changed to "30-23 Stone Yellow", 2nd and 3rd will have "---"

Comment: Can you check my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jbjaksq8/10/)

Added a value to blank options:

```
<option value="---">---</option>
```

Changed `li` click function:

```
$('.choose_variations li').click(function() {
    $('.film').val("---");
    $('.film:first').val($(this).data('val'));    
});
```